# How to modify the button's behavior on mouse over event in Graphical Installer for NSIS?

Tags: material-ui, mouseevent, nsis

I'm new to NSIS. When I truned into Graphical Installer, I found the button's reaction on mouse over event is a litter bit different from Win10's default, which supposed to turn on highlight when mouse moves in (otherwise, turn off). But buttons under Graphical Installer look dummy when mouse moves over, and highlight only when mouse clicks, just like older windows versions.

How can I modify the button's behavior to match the effect in Win10?

Comment: Without doing any kind of research I'm going to assume the buttons are handled by a custom plug-in. This is a commercial product, ask them for support...

Answer (score 0):

Buttons in **Graphical Installer for NSIS** are defined like this:

[image: Buttons]

It is a bitmap (.bmp) file with 4 button states inside of it: normal, *focused* pressed and disabled.

Size (of each state) is 83 (width) x 26 (height) pixels, together 83 x 104 pixels.

I assume you are talking about **Focused** state - you need to make the picture for this state "highlighted" - e.g. in Gimp use a function to add brightness to this area of bitmap (see the provided buttons in examples folder).

Focused state is applied when button has focus (changed e.g. by pressing the Tab button) to signalize "active" button that can be triggered by pressing the Enter key.

So this works a little different, but we will consider this "highlight" feature.

See http://graphical-installer.com/files/manuals/nsis/source/html/intro%20-%20project-graphics.html for more info

P.S. I am developer of this tool, feel free to ask any question, also asking here on SO is fine.

Comment: Update: We checked this request and implemented this feature, contact us for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really need a Win10-like effect that the Focused state being triggered not only by keyboard, but also by mouse move in. Can I do something based on the current version, or can I modify and rebuild the tool by myself?

Comment: BTW, the example "Drag and Drop" didn't work on my computer, a compile error reported as "Error in script "D:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Graphical Installer\Examples\Drag and Drop\Graphical Installer-Example.nsi" on line 22 -- aborting creation process"

Comment: And, another question I posted just now, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70240867/with-in-graphical-installer-nsis-the-text-of-label-overlapped-when-i-changed
Give me some help, thank you!