# With in Graphical Installer & NSIS, the text of Label overlapped when I changed it dynamically

Tags: label, refresh, nsis

I created a custom page which contains a label and two buttons to control the label's contents.
I suppose to **set the text** of the label within **callbacks** of the buttons, as the following codes:

```
Function FuncShowNewFeature
  ; ...
  ; Add Controls
 
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 13u 100% 12u "Show new features here"
  Pop $lblContents
  ${GraphicalInstallerRedrawLabel} $lblContents
  
  ${NSD_CreateButton} 0 -13u 40u 13u "Prev"
  Pop $btnPrev
  ${NSD_OnClick} $btnPrev PrevFeature ; callback
  
  ${NSD_CreateButton} -40u -13u 40u 13u "Next"
  Pop $btnNext
  ${NSD_OnClick} $btnNext NextFeature ; callback
  
  # Put this macro before EACH calling nsDialogs::Show to draw background properly
  ${GraphicalInstallerRedrawnsDialogsPage}
  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function NextFeature
  ${NSD_SetText} $lblContents "To show the next tip of new-feature"
  ${GraphicalInstallerRedrawLabel} $lblContents ;I don't know whether this macro is necessary here
FunctionEnd

Function PrevFeature
  ${NSD_SetText} $lblContents "To show the previous tip of new-feature"
  ${GraphicalInstallerRedrawLabel} $lblContents ;I don't know whether this macro is necessary here
FunctionEnd
```

But the result shows something wrong, which the "new" text overlapped on the old ones, just like the label has not been refreshed/cleared before redrawing.

[image]

Did I miss any necessary calling in my process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **GraphicalInstaller::SubclassLabel /NOUNLOAD $variable_name**

The correct code:

```
Function FuncShowNewFeature
  ; ...
  ; Add Controls
 
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 13u 100% 12u "Show new features here"
  Pop $lblContents
  ${GraphicalInstallerRedrawLabel} $lblContents
  GraphicalInstaller::SubclassLabel /NOUNLOAD $lblContents # <<< ADDED HERE
  
  ${NSD_CreateButton} 0 -13u 40u 13u "Prev"
  Pop $btnPrev
  ${NSD_OnClick} $btnPrev PrevFeature ; callback
  
  ${NSD_CreateButton} -40u -13u 40u 13u "Next"
  Pop $btnNext
  ${NSD_OnClick} $btnNext NextFeature ; callback
  
  # Put this macro before EACH calling nsDialogs::Show to draw background properly
  ${GraphicalInstallerRedrawnsDialogsPage}
  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function NextFeature
  ${NSD_SetText} $lblContents "To show the next tip of new-feature"
FunctionEnd

Function PrevFeature
  ${NSD_SetText} $lblContents "To show the previous tip of new-feature"
FunctionEnd
```

*GraphicalInstaller::Subclass[CONTROL]* is part of
${GraphicalInstallerRedraw[CONTROL]} macro.

This works fine for [CONTROL] of type RadioButton or CheckBox, but it is missing in Label.

We will fix this in next release, sorry for this inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

One simple workaround is to just hide the label while you update its text:

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
Page Custom gfxpage

Function onClick
Pop $0
System::Call 'kernel32::GetTickCount()i.r0' ; "Arbitrary" number
ShowWindow $2 0
${NSD_SetText} $2 "$0$0$0"
ShowWindow $2 1
FunctionEnd

Function .onInit
InitPluginsDir
File /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\image.bmp "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\nsis-r.bmp"
FunctionEnd

Function gfxpage
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateButton} 0 -13u 100% 12u "Click me"
Pop $1
${NSD_OnClick} $1 onClick

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Hello, welcome to nsDialogs!"
Pop $2
SetCtlColors $2 000000 transparent

${NSD_CreateBitmap} 0 0 100% 12u ""
Pop $3
${NSD_SetBitmap} $3 $PLUGINSDIR\image.bmp $4

nsDialogs::Show
${NSD_FreeBitmap} $4
FunctionEnd
```